# What is WebKitErrorDomain error code 204?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

If I load a page in UIWebView that contains video then the video plays successfully but didFailLoadWithError: gets called with an error code of 204.

Where can I find out what this error code is?

Initially I was loading a .3gp video, but then downloaded some sample videos off [Apple's web site](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1425)

but playing these results in the same error too.

Answer (score 4):

`WebkitErrorDomain` Code 204 is `Plug-in handled load`. It occur because it load video not from UIWebView. Maybe it uses `MPInlineMoviePlayerController` plugin.